# Rotating a parabola

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

Say I have the equation of a parabola in the complex plane:

$|z-ih| = |z-(x+ib)|$

i. e. the set of all points $z = x+iy$ in the complex plane which are equidistant from the focus $f = ih$ and the line $r = x + i b$, where $b$ and $h$ are real and distinct. Is it then correct to say that
$\big|\frac{z-z_0}{e^{i\theta}} -ih\big| = \big|\frac{z-z_0}{e^{i\theta}}-(x+ib)\big|$ is the equation of the parabola I would obtain by rotating the original parabola by an angle $\theta$ and then translating that parabola by $z_0$?

I am using an online complex locus plotter (https://www.geogebra.org/m/FzmbuJd5) and it makes the parabola rotate into a hyperbola. So, am I wrong or this plotter is not quite accurate?

Example of the geogebra plotter with $z_0 = 0$ and $\theta = \pi/2$. The focus is $f = i$ and the directrix is $x-2i$ It plots a hyperbola instead of a rotated parabola.
[image]

Comment: Your link leads to an example of an ellipse. What did you do to the plotter to construct your curve? Please explain **in the question** by editing the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand the notation, but the focus and directrix have to be rotated and translated along with the parabola, and the equation needs to reflect this.

Comment: Well they do, if you multuply and divide the focus by $e^{i\theta}$, and carry out from the modulus the $e^{i\theta}$ at the denominetor, you both rotate the focus $f = ih$ and the directrix $x+ib$.

Comment: I suggest trying to rotate the focus and directrix directly and see if the plot gives the expected parabola: One risky step in the deduction of the equations as stated is the subtraction of $z_0$ inside the magnitudes. It isn't true generally that $|z| = |w|$ if and only if $|z - z_0| = |w - z_0|$.

Comment: When I write the translated and rotated version $w = (z-z_0)/e^{i\theta}$, what I am asking is that the points $w$, represents a classic parabola $w = x +iax^2$ for some real $a$, right? So that $z = z_0 + we^{i\theta}$ .

Comment: i. e. a rotated and translated parabola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original (unrotated) equation works because the plotter treats
$x$ as equal to $\Re(z)$ (the real part of $z$) by definition.
Hence $z - x = i\Im(z)$ (where $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$, which the plotter treats as equal to  $y$ by definition)
Hence $z-(x+ib)$ works out to $iy - ib$ and $\lvert z-(x+ib)\rvert$ works out to
$\lvert y - b\rvert$, the distance from $z$ to the line $y = b$.

The problem seems to be that $x$ in the "rotated" equation is still $\Re(z)$, and subtracting $\Re(z)$ from $ze^{-i\theta}$ does not give you $\Im(z)$ or any other expression that gives you the distance to a directrix line.
Instead, it's giving you some factor times the distance to some line, so that you get a hyperbola rather than a parabola,
although I have not worked out what line and what factor.
(You get a hyperbola when the distance from each point to the directrix is $r$ times the distance to the focus, for some constant $r$ with $0 < r < 1$.)

Here's a formula that seems to work after a fashion, but only for rotation around $0$:

$$
 \left\lvert \frac{z}{e^{i\theta}}-ih \right\rvert
 = \left\lvert y\cos(\theta)-x\sin(\theta) - b \right\rvert. 
$$

A Geogebra formula (with $\theta = \frac32\pi$ as an example) is
`abs(z/exp(i*pi*1.5)-i)=abs(y*cos(pi*1.5)-x*sin(pi*1.5)-2)`.

What I think you want is

$$
 \left\lvert \frac{z - z_0}{e^{i\theta}} - ih \right\rvert
 = \left\lvert \Im\left(\frac{z - z_0}{e^{i\theta}}\right) - b \right\rvert,
$$

but I have not figured out how to express that explicitly in Geogebra.
An equivalent expression is
$$
 \left\lvert \frac{z - (p+iq)}{e^{i\theta}} - ih \right\rvert
 = \left\lvert (y-q)\cos(\theta)-(x-p)\sin(\theta)
     - b \right\rvert,
$$
where $z_0 = p + iq$ for real $p$ and $q$.
For $z_0 = 2 + i3$ and $\theta = 1.5\pi$, a Geogebra formula is
`abs((z-(2 + i*3)/exp(i*pi*1.5)-i)=abs((y-3)*cos(pi*1.5)-(x-2)*sin(pi*1.5)-1)`.

Comment: Of course, thanks, that's exactly the formula I was looking for. Of course I forgot to put the Im function.